# chef environment specific role not applied

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I am trying to bootstrap a node with a specific role that I have created to a specific environment. But the role is not applied.

For Ex: I have created Environment testing and created a environment specific role testingrole.

Is it possible to bootstrap like this?

knife bootstrap macinename -r 'role[testingrole]' -x root -i ../cskey/chef.pem

When I try to do this, it only does bootstraping, no cookbooks synced.

Comment: I guess my testingrole is not visible here, Any idea why?

Comment: Could you share your `testingrole` code? Also, what's in the environment's code? Third point, you're not adding your node to the `testing` environment. Exactly what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi,You are right. Once I included the environment -E option it started working